# Displaying an average of two variables

Tags: javascript, average, display

I'm having trouble displaying the average number of clicks per round a user does for a challenge.  When I go into the console I am able to calculate the average number, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to display.

JFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tglas/tkL4p8on/5/

My CSS:

```
<div>
  round:<span id="rounds">1</span>
</div>

<div >
  clicks:<span id="clicks">0</span>
</div>
<div>
  Average:<span id="avgDisplay">0</span>
</div>

<button id="reset">
  New Round
</button>

<button id="option1">
  Option 1
</button>

<button id="option2">
  Option 2
</button>
```

And JS:

```
var roundsDisplay = document.querySelector("#rounds");
var clicksDisplay = document.querySelector("#clicks");
var option1 = document.querySelector("#option1")
var option2 = document.querySelector("#option2");
var reset = document.querySelector("#reset")
var rounds = 1;
var clicks = 0;
var avg = clicks / rounds;


option1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  clicks++;
  clicksDisplay.innerHTML = clicks;
})

option2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  clicks++;
  clicksDisplay.innerHTML = clicks;
})

reset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  rounds++;
  roundsDisplay.innerHTML = rounds;
})

avgDisplay.innerHTML = avg;
```

I know I am probably missing something fundamental here, but I'm new to programming and would appreciate any help figuring out this concept.

Comment: Calculate the average value at each clicks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just calculating the average one time, the first time your JS file runs. But you want to calculate the average every time you increase the counter.

Just create a function that calculates the average value every time a button is pressed and create a `avgDisplay` variable. (Like Olivier mentioned in the comments)

```
var avgDisplay = document.querySelector("#avgDisplay");
function updateAverage() {
    avgDisplay.innerHTML = clicks / rounds;
}
```

and add it to your event callbacks after you've increased the counter
e.g.

```
option2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  clicks++;
  clicksDisplay.innerHTML = clicks;
  updateAverage();
})
```

Comment: Also, need to define the `avgDisplay` variable first.